# Text is hidden and takes time to show with slider in Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with my slide here http://ontwik.com/ajmi/ajmi/, when you go to next slide the text is going under the image for a while and show after changing the slide and if you tried to select the hidden text  it will show as your mouse go, this issue is a webkit only.

I'm using https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides for the slider.

Comment: USE `z-index` property on CSS ? =O

Comment: @JohnnyJS z-index didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to hack it. 
Change the slide images `backface-visibility` to `visible` inside the `li` items.

Try:

```
ul.slides-container li img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

[Read the tutorial about backface](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/)

Comment: That's awesome, first time to know about backface-visibility. Thanks Vahid